# How to take screenshot using flutter agora plugin?

Tags: flutter, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

In current agora Flutter SDK, I can't able to take screenshot. Please guide is there is any API or workaround to take a screenshot using the agora plugin

I tried to take a screenshot using the screenshot plugin(https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot#-installing-tab). But it produces a blank screen image

Please guide to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Agora Flutter SDK is using Surface View because of which you wont be able to take screenshot of the stream, as it will return with a black screen.

This is the workaround that I found for this: I used this [package instead](https://pub.dev/packages/native_screenshot)
to take the screenshot. I also have also written a sample code to illustrate agora flutter SDK and native_screenshot package. You can have a look here : https://github.com/Meherdeep/agora-videocall-demo

Note: This package is only supported for API version > 24